# html / javascript tab controllers not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery, tabs

I am currently finalising a simple website for a project I'm working on. I have two tab controls. One on the right of the page, and one on the left. Both have 3 tabs that when clicked display different content. I created one a while ago, and it has worked perfectly, I have recently returned and tried to add a second one. The problem is, when the page loads, the first one works, but the second one loads with all three content areas displayed down the page. Oddly, once I click one of the tabs on the second controller, only that tab is displayed, and the entire control seems to work correctly just like the other one.

I'm sure I have made a stupid error, but I just cant seem to find it. Any help would be massively appreciated.

My code is below:

```
<div id="graphWrapper">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#" class="defaulttab" rel="tabs1">Daily</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="tabs2">Gender</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="tabs3">Age</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tabs1">Graph Content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tabs2">Graph Content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tabs3">Graph Content 3</div>
    </div>

<div id="reportWrapper">
        <ul class="tabs2">
            <li><a href="#" class="defaulttab2" rel2="tabsR1">Report 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel2="tabsR2">Report 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel2="tabsR3">Report 3</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div class="tab-content2" id="tabsR1">Report Content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-content2" id="tabsR2">Report Content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-content2" id="tabsR3">Report Content 3</div>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {


            $('.tabs2 a').click(function(){
                switch_tabs2($(this));
            });

            switch_tabs($('.defaulttab'));
            switch_tabs2($('.defaulttab2'));

    });

        function switch_tabs(obj)
        {
        $('.tab-content').hide();
        $('.tabs a').removeClass("selected");
        var id = obj.attr("rel");

        $('#'+id).show();
        obj.addClass("selected");
        chart3.invalidateSize();
        chart4.invalidateSize();
        chart5.invalidateSize();
        }

        function switch_tabs2(obj2)
        {
        $('.tab-content2').hide();
        $('.tabs2 a').removeClass("selected2");
        var id2 = obj2.attr("rel2");

        $('#'+id2).show();
        obj2.addClass("selected2");

        }


    </script>
```

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an exception being thrown at `chart3.invalidateSize();`. This exception prevents switch_tabs2() from ever being invoked.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: chart3 is not defined
```

You can see that an exception is being encountered by using your browser's dev tools:

- Chrome: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging
- Firefox: http://getfirebug.com/javascript
- Internet explorer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope that helps!

Comment: Removing the .invalidateSize(); does make both work perfectly, do you know how i could invalidate the chart size another way? And why doest this effect the other controller? Thanks

Comment: As soon as an exception is encountered, javascript ends the current thread of execution. That means no code after the `chart3.invalidateSize()` call is run at all, which means switch_tabs2() is never invoked. With respect to invalidateSize(), I don't know what you're trying to accomplish there. The DOM elements in your example will automatically resize to fit their content. Perhaps you're using a charting library of some sort which has an invalidateSize() call? Regardless, `chart3` was never defined in your example, so you won't be able to call anything on it without having first defined it.

Comment: All fixed! Thanks very much for all your help. I am indeed using amcharts to produce graphs from an sql db ... I had read the documentation on invalidateSize() incorrectly, and have now moved it to its correct position. Its all working perfectly, thanks again!